# Socket.BeginSend does not complete synchronously despite plenty of buffer space

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

Why does `Socket.BeginSend` go asynchronous so quickly and so unpredictably? I know it's supposed to be asynchronous, but it can also complete immediately, in which case `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` is set. I would expect `CompletedSynchronously` to be true until the 8KB send buffer is filled up. The test case below (cleanup code stripped for brevity) demonstrates that `BeginSend` goes asynchronous on (typically) 3rd iteration after buffering only 6 bytes of data:

```cs
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 35001);
listener.Start();
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 35001));
Socket server = listener.AcceptSocket())
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    bool sent = false;
    IAsyncResult result = client.BeginSend(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 0, 3,
        SocketFlags.None, r => sent = true, null);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.CompletedSynchronously, // fails typ. on 3rd iteration
        String.Format("Asynchronous on iteration {0}", i));
    Assert.IsTrue(sent);
    client.EndSend(result);
}
```

The exact iteration when it goes asynchronous is somewhat random. When process starts, it's 3. Afterwards it's 1 for all new sockets. I've seen other numbers sporadically. I know the 8KB socket send buffer is there, because `Socket.Send` (with `Socket.Blocking = false`) stops at about 8KB.

Method `Socket.SendAsync` behaves similarly except it always completes asynchronously (i.e. no attempt at direct buffer write). See my [related question about Socket.SendAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345297/when-does-socket-sendasync-complete-synchronously).

I need `BeginSend` to be mostly synchronous for performance reasons (asynchronous callbacks are slower). Not to mention the unpredictability ruins unit tests and benchmarks for my low-level communication code.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general.  The rate at which a modern processor can generate data is easily two orders of magnitude higher than it could ever be sent across a network.  The only way you are going to get synchronous sends is when you artificially delay your BeginSend calls.  The point of BeginSend is to not do that.

Comment: @Hans Notice that I am calling `Socket.EndSend` in the loop. That means the previous send is already completed. There's nothing to wait for and therefore no need for asynchronous completion.

Comment: @Hans Also I wouldn't be that sure about processor speed. My older benchmarks clearly show that `Send` with `Blocking = false` is significantly faster than `BeginSend`. It might be caused by overhead of many small packets targeted at large number of IPs.

Comment: Of course it is faster, the point of async is that you can do something else and don't otherwise have a thread that doesn't do anything useful.  But async has non-zero overhead.  Calling EndSend() that quickly is pointless, just call the non-async Send() instead.

Comment: @Hans The example is just a simple demonstration of the problem. In my real app, I would of course handle both synchronous and asynchronous completion. This question is more about understanding the .NET API, i.e. why does it insist on asynchronous callbacks and why is it unpredictable.