# When does Socket.SendAsync complete synchronously?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Socket.BeginSend does not complete synchronously despite plenty of buffer space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344947/socket-beginsend-does-not-complete-synchronously-despite-plenty-of-buffer-space)

Documentation for [`Socket.SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync.aspx) says that its return value indicates either pending asynchronous operation (returns true) or an immediately completed operation (returns false).

In my case the return value is always true: all send requests result in an asynchronous callback when complete and `SendAsync` never completes synchronously.

Why doesn't it just put the data in the 8KB system send buffer and return? What is it waiting for?

You can see it with simple test case (cleanup code stripped):

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 35001);
listener.Start();
Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 35001));
Socket server = listener.AcceptSocket();
SocketAsyncEventArgs asyncArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
asyncArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }, 0, 3);
bool pending = client.SendAsync(asyncArgs);
Assert.IsFalse(pending); // fails - asynchronous operation is pending
```

My motivation is performance. I would like to have most sends completed synchronously since they are a little faster. Without synchronous completion, I would have to handle 2 million asynchronous callbacks per second in addition to already CPU-intensive application logic.

Comment: @pst UDP is not an option at the moment. I have added further explanation to the question regarding performance.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that UDP is used: just perhaps that, since Socket is morphic-over-protocols, some behavior might only be encountered in specific configurations/stacks.

Comment: I am wondering why was this closed as an _exact_ duplicate. It's different API introduced in different version of .NET Framework that behaves quite differently from the `Socket.BeginSend` discussed in the other question.